# Xcode 9 module cyclic dependencies: Darwin -> std -> Darwin

Tags: ios, xcode

Since opening my project in Xcode 9 (previously 8.2) several static library and framework targets are failing to compile with a large number of errors.  This cyclic dependency error is always at the top.

One example is a static library target for libzip. The problems stem from this single #include for the system's zlib library:

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

**Most targets can work around this by disabling modules** with the build setting *Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)*.

I have a Swift/C framework that defines a couple of modules and this isn't a solution.

Many of the errors are to do with `tgmath.h`, which is somewhat infamous for playing badly with modules. I am not sure why tgmath is even being included - it's marked explicit in the Darwin modulemap. I would love to inspect `<module-includes>:28` but I'm not sure how.

Here is an example of the compilation error. Does anybody know how to fix this in Xcode 9?

```
While building module 'zlib' imported from /Users/.../lib/zipint.h:40:
While building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stddef.h:46:
While building module 'std' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/usr/include/tgmath.h:31:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ctype.h:39:15: fatal error: cyclic dependency in module 'Darwin': Darwin -> std -> Darwin
#include_next <ctype.h>
              ^
1 error generated.
While building module 'zlib' imported from /Users/.../lib/zipint.h:40:
While building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stddef.h:46:
In file included from <module-includes>:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/tgmath.h:37:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/usr/include/tgmath.h:31:10: fatal error: could not build module 'std'
#include <complex.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
While building module 'zlib' imported from /Users/.../lib/zipint.h:40:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/usr/include/zlib.h:34:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/usr/include/zconf.h:247:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/stddef.h:46:15: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include_next <stddef.h>
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
In file included from /Users/.../lib/zip_get_compression_implementation.c:36:
/Users/.../lib/zipint.h:40:10: fatal error: could not build module 'zlib'
#include <zlib.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end the problem was a legacy custom *Header Search Path*. It had an explicit reference into the SDK, `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`. Including those headers in the search path was messing up the dependency cycle protection.